# Start workflow using App only client context

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spcontext

I use CSOM with client contex which I get from app, the App has following permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests  AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I can normally work: create lists, libraries, etc..., but if I run workflow it going to suspend status and shows following error:

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to
>   https://testsite.sharepoint.com/sites/HP/Test/_api/sp.utilities.utility.ResolvePrincipalInCurrentcontext?input='i%3A0i.t%7C00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000%7Capp%40sharepoint'&scopes='15'&sources='15'&inputIsEmailOnly='false'&addToUserInfoList='False'&matchUserInfoList='true'
>   Correlation Id: d0f3bddc-33e9-0d7c-a534-1c914cd47284 Instance Id:
>   5403283b-20a5-4855-8673-c40ef5ddfd94
>
> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.  Retry now

So my question, is it possible to run workflow using app only context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that it requires to has been activated the feature "Workflows can use app permissions"
Also the workflow will be run under SHAREPOINT\APP user.